# Proving absolute convergence of a series containing parameter

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^a}, a>0 $$ $$ 0<x<\pi$$

Now, I have to show for which values of $a$ the series absolutely converges and diverges.

I have figured out that the series converges for $a>1$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^a}| \le \frac{1}{n^a}$$
which converges for $a>1$ so we proved the absolute convergence of our series but only for $a>1$

However, I have no idea how to prove that the series **does not absolutely converge** for $0<a\le1$.

I tried finding a lower bound for $|\sin(nx)|$ but all I could come up with is that it is greater than or equal to zero which does not mean anything. Could anyone shed some light?

Comment: @Eric Sorry no. What I meant was $|\sin(nx)| \ge 0$

Comment: Okay, question edited.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum | \frac {\sin (\frac {n\pi} 2)} {n^{a}}| \geq \sum | \frac {\sin (\frac {(2n+1)\pi} 2)} {(2n+1)^{a}}| =\sum \frac 1 {(2n+1)^{a}}=\infty$ for any $a \in (0,1]$.

Comment: Can I have some more clarification? Why did you put $\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})$ if it said any x from (0,π)? And any info why $2n+1$ instead of, say, $n+1$

Comment: We are asked to find $a$ such that series converges absolutely for every $x$. To show that this condition fails for $a \leq 1$ it is enough to find one value of $x$ for which it fails and I took $x=\frac {\pi} 2$. To show that the series does not converge for this value of $x$ it is enough to show that the odd terms of the series add up to $\infty$ since the total sum is greater than or equal to the sum of the odd terms. The odd terms are obtained by replacing $n$ by $2n+1$.  @johndoe

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos nx}{n^a}, \quad x\ne 2k\pi
$$
converges conditionally for every $a>0$.

This is shown using Abel's summation method: Set $s_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \cos kx$, and then observe that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\cos kx}{k^a}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s_k(x)-s_{k-1}(x)}{k^a}=
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s_k(x)}{k^a}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s_{k-1}(x)}{k^a} \\
=
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s_k(x)}{k^a}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{s_{k}(x)}{(k+1)^a}=\frac{s_n(x)}{n^a}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}s_k(x)\left(\frac{1}{k^a}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^a}\right).
$$
Next observe that $s_n(x)$ is bounded for a fixed $x\ne 2k\pi$ and

$$
\frac{1}{k^a}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^a}=\frac{a}{k^{a+1}}+\mathcal O(k^{-a-2}),
$$
and hence the sequence
$$
\frac{s_n(x)}{n^a}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}s_k(x)\left(\frac{1}{k^a}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^a}\right).
$$
converges.